# Criar uma div com links para redes sociais

Tags: css, html5

Galera, boa tarde.

Gostaria de uma ajuda para criar uma div com 3 imagens para redes sociais, porém gostaria que elas estivessem divididas em partes iguais, assim como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até agora meu código `HTML` e `CSS` está assim:

```
<div class="footer-img">
    <div class="figure">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <figure>
              <img src="instagram.png" alt="#" style="width: 25px;">
              <figcaption>LEGENDA</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="figure">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <figure>
              <img src="youtube.png" alt="#" style="width: 35px;">
              <figcaption>LEGENDA</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="figure">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <figure>
              <img src="facebook.png" alt="#">
              <figcaption>LEGENDA</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .footer-img {
        background-color: #F09300;
        color: #FFF; 
        width: 100%;
    }

    .figure {
        display: inline-block; 
        width: 20%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .figure:hover {
        background-color: #f7c27b;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .figure a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF !important;
    }

    .figure img {
        display: inline !important;
        width: 25px;
    }

    .figure figcaption {
        display: inline !important;
        vertical-align: super !important;
    }
</style>
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc pode substituir o `display:inline-block` por `flex`, e dividir as `div`s em tamanhos iguais usando o `width` com `calc` dessa forma `width: calc(100% / 3)`

Veja como fica no modelo abaixo.

```css
.footer-img {
    background-color: #F09300;
    color: #FFF; 
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.figure {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.figure:hover {
    background-color: #f7c27b;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.figure a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF !important;
}

.figure img {
    display: inline !important;
    width: 25px;
}

.figure figcaption {
    display: inline !important;
    vertical-align: super !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-img">
    <div class="figure">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <figure>
                <img src="instagram.png" alt="#" style="width: 25px;">
                <figcaption>LEGENDA</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="figure">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <figure>
                <img src="youtube.png" alt="#" style="width: 35px;">
                <figcaption>LEGENDA</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="figure">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <figure>
                <img src="facebook.png" alt="#">
                <figcaption>LEGENDA</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, era justamente o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @PedroPaulo de nada meu jovem, tmj